# Browser launch is slow on ubuntu 13.04 64-bit

Tags: 13.04, firefox, 64-bit, google-chrome

Google chrome takes 16 seconds to start initially. I haven't added any extensions .Same with the Firefox which takes about 10 seconds to start while on windows 7 it is at most 5-6 seconds.
I have a dell Vostro 1014 with 2.1 GHz core 2 duo,2 GB Ram and running Ubuntu 13.04 64bit since 15 days.

Please provide me a good solution for this.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: i have Installed preload, how long is it going to take before it shows improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `preload`.  As far as I can remember it is a utility which analyses your usage patterns and preloads the relevant libraries to memory, thereby reducing the startup times of your applications.  It certainly won't do any harm.

To install from the official repo's do:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

from the command line.